# How to know if a checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, angular, checkbox, dom-events

Here is the code:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Blue" (click)="var=$event.target.getAttribute('value')" />
```

When I to print `var` on console, I get the `value` of the checkbox  '`Blue`' but what if I want to get if the checkbox is checked or not?

I have tried this but I get `undefined`:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Blue" (click)="var=$event.target.getAttribute('checked')" />
```

Comment: [ngModel](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/NgModel-directive.html) might be a better solution for getting user input.

Comment: My goal is to have multiple checkboxes and send to a pipe the checkbox state and the value. I dont think ngModel would be good in this case because it would bind to all checkboxes right?

Comment: I mean if i click in one checkbox, all the others checkboxs would be checked/clicked

Comment: Not if you use different models for each checkbox. For example, `<input type="checkbox" value="Blue" [(ngModel)]="blue"` and `<input type="checkbox" value="Red" [(ngModel)]="red"`, etc. will set those fields in the controller (see the first example in the page I linked).

Comment: That way i would have to send 2 params to the pipe: red and blue, right?. I would like to send just one by turning var into an obejct containg the checkbox value and state.

Comment: If you wish to get value and state info, just make it an object. For example, in the controller do something like `colors = {}` and in the template do `<input type="checkbox" value="Blue" [(ngModel)]="colors['blue']"`. Then when the user checks it you'll have `colors = {blue: true}`

Comment: Thank you @tcooc :) Your comments will be usefull in future. I am not sure why but i cant upvote your last comment

Comment: I've posted an answer version of my comments, since it seems that it's how you wanted the code to work. Feel free to mark an answer as accepted, or comment on it if you have more concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store the name and values of the checkboxes for each input in an key-value pair, [ngModel](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/NgModel-directive.html) is a good tool for this.

If your html is like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Red" [(ngModel)]="colors['red']"
<input type="checkbox" value="Blue" [(ngModel)]="colors['blue']"
```

You can put this in the controller:

```
colors = {};
```

After user input on the checkboxes, the value of the object will be updated to something like:

```
colors = {
    red: true,
    blue: false
};
```

Comment: Is it possible to iterate `colors`?

Comment: @Elkin Yes, see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Blue" (click)="var=$event.target.checked" />
```